# Char array in C

Tags: c, linux, char

I define a function

```
void add(char *key, char *value) {
}
```

And I have a string

```
char * message = "hello world"
```

I want to call add("hello", "world"), so I write

```
add(message[0,4], message[6, 10])
```

It does not work, I am refused with the "char *" and "char array", who can explain for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C you don't have ranges as in Python.

You must first create two arrays

```
char key[] = "Hello";
char value[] = "World";
```

then you pass them to your function:

```
add(key, value);
```

If you want to copy part of message as you asked, you first define a large enough buffer:

```
char buffer[100];
char buffer2[100];
```

then you copy using `strncpy()` function declared in string.h header.

```
strcnpy(buffer, message, 5); // copy Hello
strcnpy(buffer2, message + 6, 5); // copy World
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't substring a string that way in C. Here's a decent, accessible description of how to do what you want: http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx8.html

Answer (score 0):

`message[0,4]` is not valid C syntax.  You must be confusing C with another language.

If you want to make copies of the parts of this string into other arrays, you might look into allocating some space and then memcpy'ing into it.  You can't use strcpy because the first part wouldn't be null terminated.

C doesn't have a lot of simple string manipulation functions built in - you have to make space for the string, do what you want to it, and make sure it's null terminated all "by hand".

Comment: It is valid, but doesn't do anything remotely close to what you want, and is quite useless.